# Chronologically relevant

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I am looking for the word that expresses the relevancy of an event as it follows the next in a series. But the relevancy is NOT from one event to another (especially no causality); the events follow each other in a manner that is chronologically relevant to another situation. All the "synchro"  words denote simultaneity (e.g. "synchronicity"). I want to denote sequence.

Comment: Please specify whether you want a noun or something else. Also, you didn't give any context.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you saying the *events* have no inherent chronological relationship to one another, and that they only have relevance to "another situation" ***if*** they occur in some specific sequence? Or that *whichever* sequence they occur in, it's actually ***the sequence itself*** that's relevant to something?

Comment: The events are only related by the fact that they follow one another in time. They have no causal link. But their sequence is relevant to another situation. I came up with "timely" but suspect there might be a more specific word.

Comment: Developments N, O, P ... reflect the sequentiality of events A, B, C....

Answer (score 3):

***[Subsequent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subsequent)*** - following in time, order, or place

***[Successive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/successive)*** - following each other without interruption

Answer (score 0):

Consider **temporally**.

```
Definition:
```

In a certain order, with regards to time. The term describes how things are related to each other in terms of time.

```
Examples:
```

- *I thought the two events that I wanted to attend were at the same
  time, but I later found out they were temporally arranged, which
  meant that I could attend one and then the other without missing
  anything*.
- *The organization of the processes was temporally planned
  and executed which reaped dividends for the departmental production
  this new year*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the exact answers, however based on the question, I think such events can be described as **time-ordered**, **time-related** or **order-related** events.

Answer (score 0):

The correct word I was looking for is "synchronicity" but in the meaning intended by Carl Jung rather than the Webster definition... The meanings are quite different: Jung's meaning applies to events that appear to be related but without any temporal, nor any cause and effect relationships; Webster's definition focuses on the temporal (i.e. simultaneity). 
Oh well, the wonders of language. What a great site. Now I have something to go to when baffled. Thank you for the input!